# JQuery if line of text starts with character, wrap whole line in span

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have some text and i need to give a different color to the lines that start with a certain character.
what i have so far is this:

```js
var msgText = $(".msgInfo").html();
var textLines = msgText.split("<br>");
$(textLines).each(function(line, text) {
  if (text.indexOf("&gt;&gt;") == 0) {
    $(".msgInfo").html(function(i, html) {
      return html.replace(text, "<span style=\"color:#BFBFBF;\">" + text + "</span>");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="msgInfo">Nova mensagem 2<br><br>Cumpts;<br>Josue<br>Apt 253<br><br>&gt;&gt;Nova mensagem 1<br>&gt;&gt;<br>&gt;&gt;<br>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;Como sei para que enviei a mensagem? Preciso de um campo que diga para quem foi a mensagem?<br>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;<br>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;<br>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;Mensagem
  de teste para verificar o nome de quem enviou o email.<br>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;<br>&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;<br>&gt;&gt;<br></div>
```

but it's not wrapping all lines. only the ones with text other than ">>" in them.

what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the HTML you're using

Comment: Well if looks like you are selecting all of the .msgInfo elements.... not the one you are looking at the text of.

Comment: @epascarello there is only one

Comment: Well you are just wrapping all the text, not each line.

Comment: What @epascarello means is that you need to have a node for each line of text. Since there is only one <div> node it will wrap the node in <span> tags, and thus, apply the style to all text inside of it.

Comment: Also: could you show a brief example of the expected input and the expected output after the script runs?

Comment: @Our_Benefactors that's not what's happening, tho. it's actually wrapping 3 of the lines of text which start with "&gt;&gt;". that's what's supposed to happen, only i need it to happen  to all lines that start with those characters, not just 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That replacing seems to be a bit nasty and costly. How about something like:

```
var msgText = $(".viewMessage .msg .msgInfo").html();
var newText = '';
var textLines = msgText.split("<br>");
$(textLines).each(function(line,text){
    if (text.indexOf("&gt;&gt;") == 0){
        if (text.indexOf("&gt;&gt;") == 0){
        text = "<span style=\"color:#BFBFBF;\">" + text +"</span>";
    } 
    newText += text;
});
$(".viewMessage .msg .msgInfo").html(newText);
```

Be careful though. As epascarello pointed out, your jquery selector `$(".viewMessage .msg .msgInfo")` could select multiple elements. You should make sure it grabs a single element or do the "textreplace" for all of the found elements if that is desired.